# retrieving data from a mapping table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two entities that have many to many relationship:

and a join table in between

Student.java:

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="STUDENT_TEACHER", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TEACHER_ID"))

    private Collection<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
```

Teacher.java:

```
@ManyToMany
private Collection<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();
```

I use criteria to retrieve all students like:

```
studentList = session.createCriteria(Student.class).list();
```

But now I want a list of students who are under `Teacher id=2`, while the mapping table `STUDENT_TEACHER` is not class, how can it be retrieved in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire an HQL, like,

```
SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.teachers.id = 2
```

Also, inverse side of the `many to many` relationship is not present in your Teacher class. It should be annotated with below code:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="teachers")
private Collection<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Comment: So formulas in the hql represent the class/variable’s name in other column??

Comment: It'll be converted into join by Hibernate.

Comment: I changed the name of the list variable up there, does this make any difference? also, the mappedby annotation I can place it only in the teacher class. anyway i can retrieve the students of a specific teacher?

Comment: I've changed the HQL in accordance with the change in the field name. If you want bi-directional mapping b/w Teacher and Student then only @ManyToMany is required in Teacher class.

Comment: It works! I just added mappedby in student.java above teacher’s list

Comment: By the way, the one that worked is the first hql you hjust posted, could you please cancel the edit and make it like it was”with the join”